# Adding trailing slash to sitemap

Tags: sitemap, expressionengine, trailing-slash

Would it be possible to add a trailing slash on the sitemap?

For example my current sitemap :

```
<url>
<loc>
    https://www.website.com.au/shop/category/laser-therapy/capillus272-laser-cap
</loc>
<lastmod>2018-09-24T10:12:15+09:30</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
```

I want to add a trailing slash on this part https://www.website.com.au/shop/category/laser-therapy/capillus272-laser-cap

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would certainly be possible. in yor template that generates the xml file, do something like:

```
<loc>
    {page_url}/
</loc>
```

Comment: Thanks Jelle. This worked for me big time. Appreciate your help :)